# request paramater id always returns same value

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to fetch single document from db with id parameter

```
const router = express.Router();
// middleware for base url
server.use("localhost/api/v1", tasksRouter);
router
  .route("/tasks/:id")
  .get(controllers.getSingleTask)

const getSingleTask = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const taskID = req.params.id;
    const task = await Task.findOne({ _id: taskID });
    if (!task) {
      return res.status(404).json({ msg: `No task with ID: ${taskID}` });
    }
    return res.status(200).json({ task });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ msg: error });
  }
};
```

but every time i am making request the request.params contains parameter 'id' with same value even i am providing id value which doesn't exist and 'getSingleTask' controller returns same document.
I am using "express": "^4.17.1", and "mongoose": "^5.11.10"

i made request localhost/api/v1/tasks/somerandomid
and i logged my req.params.id and task getting after querying with id is

```
// id i am getting even after making request with 'somerandomid' as parameter
635651c3112d5405147b7e86

// since the id matches with first document of database controller 'getSingleTask' responds with the document.
{
  completed: true,
  _id: 635651c3112d5405147b7e86,
  task: 'task number 1',
  __v: 0
}
```

Comment: Can you also provide the request URL you are calling and what the actual value of `req.params.id` is?

Comment: value of req.params.id is _id of first document inside database.

Comment: You should include the URL you are calling + the value of `req.params.id`, that is logged, in your question in order to receive help.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.  I coded this up myself and I notice that _params.id_ is passed through just fine (as per whatever URL you request), the logic of checking the task and passing through the ids seems correct, and `Task.findOne` seems to be a valid mongoose-like way to get a document.  Either make this reproducible or provide more clear evidence that something is going wrong on your side.  I think I may have to vote to close because your question _needs debugging details_.

Comment: From where are you doing this request? Some Webapp in the browser? Postman? curl? With the code shown it is literally impossible, that express just assumes one fixed id regardless of what you put into the url. what is the `taskRouter` which you attach to your server but never define? And do your really have `localhost` as part of your route?

Comment: Actually the problem was with my postman messed something inside my environment so I had to create a new environment.